# SQLAlchemy filter, substr, case

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can I use a `CASE` statement within `substr` and `filter`?

Here is my requirement:

```
>> value = '00021050430' #here value is a database column
>> query.filter((func.substr(value,case([(func.length(value) > 7,func.length(varying_value)-7+1))],else_=1),7)=='1050430')
```

Output I am expecting is:

```
>> query.filter(func.substr(value,6,7))
```

The above throws an error.

Comment: Please always include the actual (full) traceback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to use a `CASE()` statement here. Just use Python:

```
query.filter(func.substr(value, 1 if len(value) > 7 else 1, 7) == '1050430')
```

This is called a conditional expression; it's constructed as `true_expr if test_expr else false_expr`, where `true_expr` is used if the `test_expr` evaluates to True, otherwise the `false_expr` part is used.

If `value` is *not* a constant but a column reference, then you *do* need to use a `CASE()` statement. Use [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) for that:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import case

query.filter(func.substr(value, case([(func.length(column) > 7, func.length(column) - 7 + 1)], else_=1), 7) == '1050430')
```

but you need to make sure your `(` and `)` parenthesis are balanced (you had one too many).